# Input string was not in a correct format. however I dont have string data

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

You can my return data and exception below. I use a web service for calling methods of classes.

```
  List<CargoOptionTo> list = ds.CargoOptionList().AsQueryable().OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord).ToList();
```

After this code, throw an exception.

[image]

And here is my returned data:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: whats the value of sidx and sord?

Comment: You have an invalid XML file. Did you read the whole exception message?

Comment: Exception says : there is an error in Xml document...

Comment: and whats up with more than 50 questions with no accepted answers. You don't like being helped or what?

Comment: What does this part return?: `OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)` Looks like a string to me. Could that be in an invalid format?

Comment: I deleted OrderBy clouse but the same result. I dont have any xml file. Web service create a xml file while returning my data.

Comment: @RuneFS - the questions which were answered are mostly answered by him/herself.

Comment: @Maarten 1) it's possible to accept your own answers 2) if your questions don't get any answers you should rephrase them to make them clearer and/or add a bounty or simply delete them after all unanswered questions are worthless and if you are not making any effort to have them answered anyways you might as well delete them

Comment: @Maarten this is a perfectly good example of why the questions are not answered. The request for more informations (e.g. the comments here) have been unanswered. probably because OP found the solution and didn't bother to update (and thereby help others with similar problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just delete my service reference and add again then it solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a lambda to define your OrderBy

ie

```
.OrderBy(x => x.SortField)
```

Comment: I think he is using dynamic linq